# if condition not met in 10 seconds then do this else do that [UnityScript]

Tags: python, unityscript

I have no idea how to come at this. In Python I could probably do it but I'm not that good with UnityScript. I was thinking something like this in Python:

```
import time 
for i in range(time):
    if(condition == True):
      #do this
    else:
       #do this
    time.sleep(1)
```

How would I come about doing this in UnityScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a normal JavaScript implementation I would suggest using `setTimeout()`, but the Unity documentation suggests using `Invoke()` (see the [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html)).

```
function doStuff() {
    if(condition == true) {
      ...
    }
    else {
        Invoke('doStuff', 1);
    }
}
```